# OrientDB import from CSV, nullValue property

Tags: orientdb, csv-import

I'm trying to import a fake CSV file into OrientDB Server 2.1.2.
The ETL tool looks amazing, allowing people to input many options, however it seems to me that the csv transformer (when I tried to use the CSV extractor I got a `Extractor 'csv' not found` error) does not interpret correctly the "nullValue" option.

I used the following JSON to try to load a simple file and, when using "NULL" as null value both in the data and in the JSON I could import the file correctly, while when using "?" I couldn't.
`

```
{
    "source": { "file": {"path": "Z:/test.tsv"}},
    "extractor": { "row": {}},
    "transformers": [
        {"csv": {
            "separator": "  ",
            "nullValue": "?",
            "columnsOnFirstLine": true,
            "columns": [
                "a:STRING",
                "b:STRING",
                "c:String",
                "n:Integer"
            ],
            "dateFormat": "dd.mm.yyyy"
            }
        },
        {"vertex": {"class": "Test", "skipDuplicates": true}}
    ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:C:/Users/taatoal1/tmp/orientdb/databases/test",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "classes": [
                {"name": "Test"}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`

Here is the data:

    `a   b   c   1
    a0  b0  c0  2
    a1  b1  c1  ?`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion is to try with (just released) latest version, 2.1.4:[Orient Download](http://orientdb.com/download/)
In 2.1.4 we add the support for the CSV extractor which internally uses commons-csv from Apache.

Comment: I've tried it: the CSV extractor is present but the problem with the "?" is still there, and disappears when I use "NULL" both in the data and in the ETL configuration. Here is  part of the output: `OrientDB etl v.2.1.4 (build @BUILD@) www.orientdb.com
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
[file] INFO Reading from file Z:/projects/employees2graph/final_data/orientdb/test.tsv with encoding UTF-8
{a:a,b:b,c:c,n:1}
{a:a0,b:b0,c:c0,n:2}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String`

Comment: Could you please fill an issue request: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-etl/issues

Comment: Hi, we  just *promoted* ETL to be part of core modules. Your issues is moved too: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5154. You can wait the next hotfix release (2.1.5) or build the etl jar from source. *NOTE*: sources are now under the main orientDB repo https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/